# Find a, f(a), f'(a) based on the graph

Tags: calculus

[image]

So derivative of a appears to be given. 
f'(a)=-3x+7

x appears to be 2.
I've tried to plug back into the Linear Approximation formula but there simply seem to be too many missing variable to make any progress along that line.

Comment: When you have the value of $a$, how do you find $f(a)$?

Comment: The corresponding y value. Is a 2 in this case?

Comment: The tangent at the point $a$ is given by $f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$. Write $-3x+7$ in the form $A(x-2)+B$ to find $f'(a)=A$ and $B=f(a)$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by $a$. It doesn't appear anywhere on the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to distinguish between $x$, which is a variable in $f(x)$ and $a$.  There is nothing in the graph to indicate that $a=2$, but I believe that is what you are supposed to find from the dot.  Taking that, the line indicates that the tangent line at $a$ is $y=-3x+7$  What is the slope of that line?  That is $f'(a)$  To get $f(2)$, note that the point is on the line $y=-3x+7$, so plug $2$ into that and you are done.